# Calculate category groups with results

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, grouping, category-theory

So we have a Drupal site with nodes tagged in 4 vocabularies. In SQL terms, these are all simply joins on a base table. In simplified terms, it looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT a.name AS location, b.name AS sector, c.name AS tag, d.name AS status
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id = n.id
WHERE n.type = 'X'
GROUP BY a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name
```

We have a listing page where you can filter by A, B, C and D; each has a list of all the values and an "All" option.

What we need is a list of distinct combinations of A, B, C and D **which have results**. This is to generate a sitemap and obviously, we don't want to guide bots to empty result pages.

I have tried using WITH ROLLUP with partial success. This gives me `a/b/c/d`, `a/b/c/*`, `a/b/*/*`, `a/*/*/*` and `*/*/*/*`. However it does not do `*/*/*/d`, `*/b/*/*` or `*/b/*/d` (along with all like-combinations).

Any suggestions on if this is possible using SQL with this approach? I wouldn't be aversed to using subqueries.

Our alternative theory is to loop through all the nodes and build an array in PHP with all the combinations that node appears under. Eg: if Node 1 was in `a/b/c/d`, then our array would have the following added to it

```
[
  'a/b/c/d',
  'a/b/c/*',
  'a/b/*/d',
  'a/*/c/*',
  'a/*/c/d',
  'a/*/*/*',
  '*/*/*/d',
  '*/b/c/d',
  '*/b/c/*',
  '*/b/*/d',
  '*/*/c/*',
  '*/*/c/d',
  '*/*/*/*',
  '*/*/*/d',
  '*/*/*/*',
]
```

(I think thats all the combinations).

The unique set of those, at the end, will be all available paths/options without any empty ones. I think.

This is obviously a bit of a brute-force approach. It feels like it would work, but it feels less elegant than doing it with SQL.

Comment: I do not really se this as an issue with the query, I think the issue is with the data. If your query does not return `*/*/*/d`, then you do not have the required records with the same `node.id` in the table. Sql was designed to return what's in the database, and not that is not in the database.

Comment: Not quite, @Shadow - this is how WITH ROLLUP works... It summarises from the right. My item exists in category d, so * (which is all) for all the others will include d.

You're right, in that this is an SQL problem... But I am unsure how to rephrase the query here. SQL is returning all the right values. Eg, for that Node, I'll get a row for `a/b/c/d` and ROLLUP will give me the `a/b/c/*`, `a/b/*/*`, `a/*/*/*` and `*/*/*/*` rows. ROLLUP will not do `*/*/*/d` though.

Comment: I do not see why you would need `rollup` if you had the right data in your tables.

Comment: The tables are a schema defined by Drupal and the Field API. I am querying a framework, not some custom tables. The SQL returns the right data. It returns, for example, a row that indicates that Node 1 is tagged with `a/b/c/d`. I need to add onto that the rows for filtering purposes for a report. Eg I know that node 1 will appear ALSO on `a/b/c/*`.

Comment: @Shadow what would the "right data in your tables" be? The data is pretty simple, an entity with 4 categories attached to it. The categories are not in a hierarchy, each is a set of tags. Just want to generate every possible url that returns data and add those to an xmlsitemap.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This doesn't work, I'm pretty sure it's not all the results

Hmm... just tried this out and it looks like you might get all possible results by using 2 queries, grouping in each direction:

ie GROUP BY a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name

then GROUP BY d.name, c.name, b.name, a.name

But then i tried adding both those grouping directions in one query and it looks quite promising:

ie GROUP BY a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name, c.name, b.name, a.name

---

I think this works but there could be a better way.

I'm using 4 queries to get all results, like this:

---

```
SELECT a.name AS location, b.name AS sector, c.name AS tag, d.name AS status
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN a ON a.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id = n.id
WHERE n.type = 'X'
GROUP BY a.name, b.name, c.name, d.name
```

---

```
SELECT b.name AS sector, c.name AS tag, d.name AS status
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id = n.id
WHERE n.type = 'X'
GROUP BY b.name, c.name, d.name
```

---

```
SELECT c.name AS tag, d.name AS status
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN c ON c.id = n.id
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id = n.id
WHERE n.type = 'X'
GROUP BY c.name, d.name
```

---

```
SELECT d.name AS status
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN d ON d.id = n.id
WHERE n.type = 'X'
GROUP BY d.name
```

---

So the first query returns all results where all 4 categories has a value, ie a/b/c/d and the roll up adds them for a/b/c/-, a/b/-/-, a/-/-/- (the the hyphens are for All filter value, asterisks vanish when i type them for some reason)

Then the second query returns everything for */b/c/d and the roll up adds -/b/c/-, -/b/-/-

The third returns -/-/c/d and the roll up adds -/-/c/-

then the fourth adds the -/-/-/d and -/-/-/-

Which i think is everything